# Discord.JS - Find if a user has a role

Tags: discord.js

I'm doing the most basic mute command ever, and I need to find if the user has a role called 'Muted'

I've added the code below, but I keep getting an error.

```
 if (command === "mute") {
    const { member, mentions } = message
     const mutee = message.mentions.users.first();  
     const muter = message.author
     console.log(mutee)

     if(member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
       let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
     if (message.guild.members.get(mutee.id).roles.cache.has(muteRole.id)) {
       message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed() .setTitle(`Uh Oh!`) .setDescription(`${mutee.user} already has been Muted!`))
     }
     else {

     }
     }
   }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: 1) Members have roles, not users. 2) you should be checking `message.guild.members.cache` not `message.guild.members`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you to get the mentioned member directly instead of the user with `const mutee = message.mentions.members.first();`. (If you are using the command under a Guild Channel)

Then, you can simply check if he has the role with:

```js
if (mutee.roles.cache.has(muteRole.id))
```

Comment: i would recommend to use `.has(muteRole.id)` insted of `.get()`